# Wifi Hardware Blocked Lenovo Thinkpad L420

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, airplane-mode

Sometimes when I restart the laptop, the wifi will turn off and can't be turned back on. I tried

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

I also pressed the airplane button on my laptop, but it still can't. My laptop's wifi adapter is indeed broken, so I bought usb wifi TPLINK wl722wn.

Comment: Are you saying that the TPLINK wifi adapter hasn't helped, that wifi still occasionally fails on boot? Presumably if you reboot then it works?

Comment: yes ubuntu wifi still doesn't work, actually my laptop has dual boot and the tplink works on my Windows 8